# ¿Como volver a pedir un valor si al ingresarlo y buscar ya se encuentra en el arreglo o estructura c++?

Tags: c++

Si tengo una solitud de datos de una estructura pero debo validar si un nombre que estoy ingresando ya existe en dicha estructura Y SI EXISTE VOLVER A PEDIRLO! como hacerlo ya que he intentado y no encuentro el modo ya que lo busco con un `for` y si lo encuentra hasta allí todo bien pero como repetir la solicitud nuevamente

```
string buscarNombre;
    for(int i=1; i<=20; i++){

        cout<<"Nombre del Caballo >> ";
        cin>>caballo[i].NomCaballo; //aqui necesito validar que este nombre ingresado no se repita
    
         buscarNombre=caballo[i].NomCaballo;
        
         for(int j=20; j>=0;j--){
           if(buscarNombre=caballo[j].NomCaballo){
                cou<<"este nombre se encuentra registrado ingresar nuevamente";
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo solicitar nuevamente el ingreso de ese valor si se encuentra ya en la estructura?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada pienso que se debe validar que el nombre no sea repetido antes de ingresar el mismo a la estructura.

Es decir que se debe tener una variable tipo string en la cual ingresar el nombre y validarlo, si este no es repetido entonces ya se puede ingresar en la estructura, de lo contrario se debe pedir que se ingrese nuevamente.

Para la validación deberias de utilizar un ciclo while o do-while.

Y el código a groso modo sería algo como.

```
const int LONGITUD = 10; //indica el tamaño de la estructura


//este seria el codigo donde validas antes de ingresarlo a la estructura
for(int i=0; i<LONGITUD; i++){
   while(nombre == caballo[i].NomCaballo){
      prinft("Nombre repetido, ingrese uno nuevo\n");
      scanf("%d", & nombre);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Amigo estuve probando lo que me dices pero no me funciona .

Comment: Creo que @Blas está trabajando con tipos string, es muy posible que tu programa estés usando char []. Ninguno de los dos habeis puesto el tipo de las variables y de ahí la confusión.